# Вместо исчезновения мерцание картинки при наведении на нее

Tags: html, css

```css
@font-face {
font-family: "OpenSans";  
src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"); 
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "OpenSansBold";  
src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"); 
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "PTSans";  
src: url("fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"); 
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal;
}


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
 max-width: 1366px;
 margin: 0 auto 0;
}

#header {
 width: 1366px;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 background-color: #252323;
 vertical-align: top;
}
#logo {
 display: inline-block;
 width:113px;
 height:23px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left: 205px;
}
#socialmedia {
 width: 194px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 26px;
 line-height: 26px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left: 650px;
}

#google {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 23px;
 height: 23px;
 line-height: 23px;
 margin-left: 27px;
}
#facebook {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 13px;
 height: 26px;
 line-height: 26px;
 margin-left: 27px;
}
#twitter {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25px;
 height: 21px;
 line-height: 21px;
 margin-left: 27px;
}
#in {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25px;
 height: 24px;
 line-height: 24px;
 margin-left: 27px;
}
#navigation {
 width: 1366px;
 height: 80px;
 line-height: 80px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

#menu{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 80px;
 margin-left: 193px;
}
#menu > a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 80px;
 line-height: 80px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu > a > p {
 display: inline-block;
 font: Regular 30px/20px OpenSans;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #8b8b8b;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left:13px;
 margin-right: 13px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu > a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #00bac6;
}


#menu > a:hover > p {
 color: #00bac6;
}

#search {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 210px;
 width: 190px;
 height: 36px;
 vertical-align: center;
 background: url('img/search.png') no-repeat center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#search:focus {
 background: white;
 border-color: red;
}
#slider {
 width: 1366px;
 height: 454px;
}
hr {
 width:1366px;
 height: 4px;
 color: #f0f0f0;
 background: #f0f0f0;
 border:none;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}


a > img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#centralinformation{
 width:1366px;
 text-align:center;
}

.header {
 margin-top: 58px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 90px;
 font-family: OpenSansBold;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #818181;
 vertical-align: text-bottom;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text {
 display:block;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-family: PTSans;
 font-weight: Regular;
 color: #818181;
}

#pictures {
 width:1366px;
 height: 385px;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 385px;
}

#tv{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 300px;
 max-height: 385px;
 line-height: 112px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 193px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tvone {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-left: 70px;
}


.tvone:hover + .tvtwo{
 display: inline-block;
}

.tvtwo{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-left: 70px;
 display: none;
}

.blocktext{
 display:inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 background:red;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 300px;
 max-height: 300px;
}

.textpictures {
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-family: PTSans;
 font-weight: Regular;
 color: #818181;
}
.textpicturesheader{
 display: block;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-family: OpenSansBold;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #818181;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

 #main {
  width:auto;
 }
 #header {
  width:auto;
 }

 #socialmedia {
  display: none;
 }
 #logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 #navigation {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 280px;
 }

 #menu {
  width:auto;
  margin-left:0px;
  height: 240px;
 }

 #menu > a {
  vertical-align: top;
  width:100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 #search {
  background: white;
  width:90%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 20px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #slider {
  display: none;
 
 }
 #centralinformation {
  width:auto; 
 }

 #centralinformation > p {
  font-size: 5px;
 }
 hr {
  display: none;
 }

}
```

```html
<section id="pictures">
  <div id="tv">
   <img class="tvone" src="https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png">
   <img class="tvtwo" src="https://c.radikal.ru/c02/1801/20/0c59372690c5.png">
   <div class="blocktext">
   <p class="textpicturesheader">Lorem Ipsum is</p>
   <p class="textpictures">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
   <p class="textpictures">and typesetting of the industry. Lorem</p>
   <p class="textpictures">Ipsum has been</p>
   </div>
  </div>

 </section>
```

Comment: Ну а что вы хотели, после исчезновения `hover` для картинки пропадает, и потому она опять принимает другой стиль и появляется, и так до бесконечности. Просто опишите что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Исправил свой код, хочу что бы просто одна картинка при наведении заменяла другую. Запустите там все понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно задать картинки как фон блоку и менять background-image при :hover. Бонус - возможность плавной смены картинки при помощи css transition.

```css
@font-face {
font-family: "OpenSans";  
src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"); 
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "OpenSansBold";  
src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"); 
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "PTSans";  
src: url("fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"); 
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal;
}


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
 max-width: 1366px;
 margin: 0 auto 0;
}

#header {
 width: 1366px;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 background-color: #252323;
 vertical-align: top;
}
#logo {
 display: inline-block;
 width:113px;
 height:23px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left: 205px;
}
#socialmedia {
 width: 194px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 26px;
 line-height: 26px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left: 650px;
}

#google {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 23px;
 height: 23px;
 line-height: 23px;
 margin-left: 27px;
}
#facebook {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 13px;
 height: 26px;
 line-height: 26px;
 margin-left: 27px;
}
#twitter {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25px;
 height: 21px;
 line-height: 21px;
 margin-left: 27px;
}
#in {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25px;
 height: 24px;
 line-height: 24px;
 margin-left: 27px;
}
#navigation {
 width: 1366px;
 height: 80px;
 line-height: 80px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

#menu{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 80px;
 margin-left: 193px;
}
#menu > a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 80px;
 line-height: 80px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu > a > p {
 display: inline-block;
 font: Regular 30px/20px OpenSans;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #8b8b8b;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left:13px;
 margin-right: 13px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu > a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #00bac6;
}


#menu > a:hover > p {
 color: #00bac6;
}

#search {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 210px;
 width: 190px;
 height: 36px;
 vertical-align: center;
 background: url('img/search.png') no-repeat center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#search:focus {
 background: white;
 border-color: red;
}
#slider {
 width: 1366px;
 height: 454px;
}
hr {
 width:1366px;
 height: 4px;
 color: #f0f0f0;
 background: #f0f0f0;
 border:none;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}


a > img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#centralinformation{
 width:1366px;
 text-align:center;
}

.header {
 margin-top: 58px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 90px;
 font-family: OpenSansBold;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #818181;
 vertical-align: text-bottom;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text {
 display:block;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-family: PTSans;
 font-weight: Regular;
 color: #818181;
}

#pictures {
 width:1366px;
 height: 385px;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 385px;
}

#tv{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 300px;
 max-height: 385px;
 line-height: 112px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 193px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tv-picture {
    height:110px;
    background:url(https://b.radikal.ru/b39/1801/6a/339592a851eb.png) no-repeat center/contain;
    transition:all .5s ease-out;
}
.tv-picture:hover{
  background-image:url(https://c.radikal.ru/c02/1801/20/0c59372690c5.png)
}
.blocktext{
 display:inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 background:red;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 300px;
 max-height: 300px;
}

.textpictures {
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-family: PTSans;
 font-weight: Regular;
 color: #818181;
}
.textpicturesheader{
 display: block;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-family: OpenSansBold;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #818181;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

 #main {
  width:auto;
 }
 #header {
  width:auto;
 }

 #socialmedia {
  display: none;
 }
 #logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 #navigation {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 280px;
 }

 #menu {
  width:auto;
  margin-left:0px;
  height: 240px;
 }

 #menu > a {
  vertical-align: top;
  width:100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 #search {
  background: white;
  width:90%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 20px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #slider {
  display: none;
 
 }
 #centralinformation {
  width:auto; 
 }

 #centralinformation > p {
  font-size: 5px;
 }
 hr {
  display: none;
 }

}
```

```html
<section id="pictures">
  <div id="tv">
            <div class="tv-picture"></div>       
   <div class="blocktext">
   <p class="textpicturesheader">Lorem Ipsum is</p>
   <p class="textpictures">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
   <p class="textpictures">and typesetting of the industry. Lorem</p>
   <p class="textpictures">Ipsum has been</p>
   </div>
  </div>

 </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

После исчезновения картинки `hover` для нее уже не действует, и потому она опять принимает другой стиль и появляется, и так до бесконечности. Просто опишите что вы хотите сделать?

Могу предложить вариант. Обернуть картинки в `div`. Фиксировать ее ширину и высоту. И прикрепить `hover` к этому `div`. Фиксация размеров для того что бы после исчезновения картинки мышка не вылезла за границы контейнера, и `hover` не пропадал.

```css
#pictures {
  width: 1366px;
  height: 385px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 385px;
}

#tv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 385px;
  line-height: 112px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 193px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.image_container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 199px;
}
.tvone {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
.image_container:hover>.tvone{
  display: none;
}

.tvtwo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  display: none;
}

.blocktext {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.textpictures {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: PTSans;
  font-weight: Regular;
  color: #818181;
}

.textpicturesheader {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: OpenSansBold;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #818181;
}
```

```html
<section id="pictures">
  <div id="tv">
    <div class="image_container">
      <img class="tvone" src="https://data.pixiz.com/output/user/frame/preview/400x400/4/8/2/5/2875284_a1ff9.jpg">
      <img class="tvtwo" src="https://a4-images.myspacecdn.com/images03/2/b7b11603c3e94cb6bfcd65329cc9a760/300x300.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="blocktext">
      <p class="textpicturesheader">Lorem Ipsum is</p>
      <p class="textpictures">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
      <p class="textpictures">and typesetting of the industry. Lorem</p>
      <p class="textpictures">Ipsum has been</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```